# REST API PUT request to update resource

Tags: php, api, laravel

I want to update one of the resources I defined (user) to update his current status (online/offline) and/or location. Therefore I would use a PUT request like this:

```
PUT http://server/v1/users/12345
```

**Payload**

```
{
   "status": 0
}
```

to set the status offline for example.

Or it could be:

**Payload**

```
{
   "latitude": 100,
   "longitude": 100
}
```

The backend is based on Laravel/PHP and I respond to this request in my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $userReference) {

        // Get payload from request
        $bodyContent = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $userReference = $userReference;

        // Update the user location
        $updateResponderLocationCommand = new UpdateResponderLocationCommand($bodyContent);
        $this->commandBus->execute($updateResponderLocationCommand);

        $response = [
            'userReference' => $userReference
        ];

        return $this->setStatusCode(201)->respond($response);
    }
```

This controller uses a command system I integrated that will trigger the task of doing the update.

My questions are, where I struggle:

1. How do I do differentiate between the commands that should be executed. Right now, only the LocationUpdate is in this method. But I don't want to write a new update message just for the status update.
2. So how does a request need to work properly? Can I still use the approach with `PUT http://server/v1/user/100` and by having keywords in the payload and a select switch - approach within the controller a differentiation between tasks to be executed upon?
3. Am I suppsoed to use PUT at all, when I only update a single component? I read that I should use POST instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Typically, the corresponding action would be sent through the routing mechanism. We would have an `action` property on your `json object` that corresponds to the function that should take place.

Lets have a look at that:

```
public function update(....){
    switch($request->get('action'))
    {
        case 'location':
            //execute the command here
            break;
        case 'status':
            //execute the command here
            break;
    }
}
```

In this way, we can make sure that our `commands` are dispatched according to our actions. This is the method that I prefer.

2. Regarding the whole put v.s. post - there's no reason to do another write-up as [this question thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest) has the best breakdown and explanation by far.
3. You should refer back to the link in #2. When creating a resource, you should use `PUT`. This makes sure that the request is idempotent and will not be duplicated (client's hung, server bottlenecked, etc).

Comment: 1. I was thinking exactly about this.... you confirmed that now.. I thought it felt somehow "inadequate" or not like the right way.... So thats awesome. 2) Thanks for the link 3) I am surprised that I should use PUT to create a resource instead of `POST`. That should be changed then in my approach.